# Is there a limit in the number of services that I should use?

Tags: android, android-service

I am developing an app for an special device that will only run this app, but 12 hours a day at least. Should I be careful with the number of services I'll use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should be, running too much services will create new tasks, instead use 1 service and divide your work in threads.

Refer [this answers link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927762/android-service-multiple-thread-design)